# How to enable intellisense [autocompletion box] for Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, settings, intellisense

I installed and reinstalled a fresh version of **Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express**

And when I type like 
System. *dot* that intellisense box should pop out with results, which I could pick from to make it easier to code.

But the box never pops out no matter what I type. I read Google for all the solutions and nothing works here is a picture of my settings.

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages
[image: All languages]
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#
[image: All languages C#]
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense
[image: IntelliSense C#]
Here is how I did the reset.. didn't change anything.
[image: chsarp reset]
[image: grayed out]
Anything else I have to do?

Comment: This happened to me once; whenever I typed anything the intellisense never popped up (using the same VS as you). All I did was quit VS and re-opened it and it worked, however this may not be the same with you.

Comment: I closed it and reopened it and even restarted computer and completely uninstalled and re-installed it.. nothing shows up. It used to work recently I had to re-install windows on top of my existing windows and registry was deleted and that must of messed something up and even uninstalling doesn't help with that.

Comment: Did you try resetting VS settings?

Comment: Yes and I set it to Expert Settings as well.